# How to set FROM (on-behalf) mail Using MS Graph which is not having mail.send permission

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

The scenario here is we have a 'domain and mailbox' enabled service account (foocompany) and registered Azure AD application with Mail.Send permission. So, when we are sending mail, the From mail is as foo@company.com

**but** the scenario here is to send mail on behalf of different account i.e from (bar@company.com), I hardcoded this but this didn't work.

How can this be achieved , using MS Graph mail.send API? Is there any workaround or hack for this?
Attached image for basic reference.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a delegated mailbox (`bar@company.com`) for your mailbox (`foo@company.com`).

Delegated mailbox is actually another mailbox and needs to be assigned an Exchange Online license. Then set the `from` property to the delegated user who have **sendAs** rights for your mailbox in Microsoft Graph API. References [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-create-send-messages#setting-the-from-and-sender-properties). After that, when you send an email, the recipient will see it's from the delegated email.

About how to assign **sendAs** rights in Exchange Admin Center, please refer to [Use the EAC to assign permissions to individual mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-permissions-for-recipients#use-the-eac-to-assign-permissions-to-individual-mailboxes). It may take several hours to take effect.

Please note that **Send on Behalf** can also allow you to send mail from the delegated user. But the recipients will see the sender is "*Delegate* on behalf of *Mailbox*".

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/sendMail
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
        },
        "toRecipients": [{
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "user@domain.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "from": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "{delegated mailbox}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```